# Why is array.findIndex returning not a fucntion. (mozilla says it basically is?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

changing `state.findIndex` to `state.ids.findIndex` resolved this issue.

**However when calling the function `onClick` it automatically updates ALL of the `active` values to `true`. rather than waiting for the click event.**

---

I am trying to set up an `onClick` method/function that will find the `active: true` and set it to `false` and then find the object with the matching `id: xxxxxx` and set that object's `active:` to `true`.

According to developer.mozilla.org and several other sites, my method should theoretically work, or, more likely I'm misinterpreting it.

This is the error it's returning
[image]

This is the function I'm trying to write - why does it return that findindex is not a function?

```
function changeActiveField(im) {
  const i = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.active === true);
  state[i].active = false;
  const index = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === im);
  state[index].active = true;
}
```

Here the `const i` finds the index of the `obj{ active: true}` and changes it to `obj{ active: false}`
then `const index` finds the `obj` with the `obj{id: value}` that matches the `im` which is passed in from the clicked component...

```
<div className="thumbs">
          {state.ids.map((i) => (
              <Image
                className="carouselitem"
                rounded
                fluid
                onClick={changeActiveField(i.id)}
                src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
                size="small"
              />
          ))}
        </div>
```

Go to https://test.ghostrez.net and navigate to the Services page to see the video menu. The small thumbnails are the "clickable" items that should trigger the `changeActiveField` function in turn setting the clicked `id` to `active: true` and changing the `activevid` div

here is the full page code.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Embed, Image, Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./Player.css";

var state = {
  ids: [
    {
      id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
      active: false,
    },
    {
      id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
      active: false,
    },
  ],
};

function firstActiveId(ids) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (ids[i].active) {
      return ids[i].id;
    }
  }
}

function changeActiveField(im) {
  const i = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.active === true);
  state[i].active = false;
  const index = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === im);
  state[index].active = true;
}

export default class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      state: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carouselwrap">
        <div className="activevid">
          <Embed
            active
            autoplay={false}
            color="white"
            hd={false}
            id={firstActiveId(state.ids)}
            iframe={{
              allowFullScreen: true,
              style: {
                padding: 10,
              },
            }}
            placeholder={
              "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +
              firstActiveId(state.ids) +
              "/hqdefault.jpg"
            }
            source="youtube"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="thumbs">
          {state.ids.map((i) => (
            <>
              <Image
                className="carouselitem"
                rounded
                fluid
                onClick={changeActiveField(i.id)}
                src={"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"}
                size="small"
              />
              <h2>
{/*this is for testing purposes only*/}
                {i.id} {i.active ? "true" : "false"}
              </h2>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `.findIndex()` is an **array** method; it looks to me like `state` is not an array.

Comment: It's the `id` property in the `state` that is an array. Use `state.id.(...)`

Comment: try state.ids.findIndex(....) Your state is an object with one ids property. The value of ids is the array you want to target.

Comment: Thanks all. that resolved that issue. for some reason it is now marking all object's active values to true. not waiting for the button click. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the state was not the array, rather ids i the array... so changing my statements to `state.ids.findIndex` solved that problem

```
function changeActiveField(im) {
  const i = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.active === true);
  state[i].active = false;
  const index = state.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === im);
  state[index].active = true;
}
```